# fill data in an array with zeros

Tags: c, arrays

I have written this part of code which opens a txt file to write the results(tokens) which strtok gives me every 10 seconds from a buffer. This buffer reads from a serial device.

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
 {
    fputs(buff,stdout);
    FILE *ft = fopen("/home/pi/Desktop/data.txt","a+");
    struct tm *tp;
    time_t t;
    char s[80];
    t = time(NULL);
    tp = localtime(&t);
    strftime(s, 80, "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S", tp);
    char *pos = strchr(buff,'N');
    if (pos)
    {
         ptr = strtok(buff, "Nodo_,=:V()");
         i = 0;
       while (ptr != NULL)
         {
          if (i == 0)
             strcat(number, ptr); 
          if (i == 2)
             strcat(temp, ptr); 
          if (i == 4)
             strcat(hr, ptr); 
          if (i == 6)
             strcat(dw, ptr); 
          if (i == 8)
             strcat(vcc, ptr); 
          ptr = strtok(NULL, "Nodo_,=:V()");
          i++;
         }
      printf("Results: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", number, temp, hr, dw, vcc);
char (*table1[1][5])[6] = {{&number, &temp, &hr, &dw, &vcc}};
       for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
       {
          fprintf(ft,"%s ",s);
          for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
          fprintf(ft,"%s ",table1[i][j]);
       }
      fprintf(ft,"\n");
      buff[sizeof(buff)-1] = '\0';
      memset(nodo, 0, sizeof(number));
      memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
      memset(hr, 0, sizeof(hr));
      memset(dw, 0, sizeof(dw));
      memset(vcc, 0, sizeof(vcc));
      printf("\n");

     }
fclose(ft);
  }
close_port(fd);
```

I have this kind of results in my txt

```
19/06/2013  13:16:34 7 20.83 51.79 11.05 4.85 
19/06/2013  13:16:34 10 21.83 53.79 12.05 3.85
```

Every number 7 or 10 returns 4 numbers as you can see from the results. I would like to create the following:
if number=7 then

```
20.83 51.79 11.05 4.85 0 0 0 0
```

if number=7 then

```
 0 0 0 0 21.83 53.79 12.05 3.85
```

I mean I want to have an array of zeros. Then if the number=7 put the values in the positions 0-3, clean the array, if the number=10 then put the values in positions 4-7. Any good idea?

Comment: The question is not clear. If setting an array with zeroes is the problem, then you can use `memset` function.

Comment: No I know that with memset I can set an array with zeros, my question is how can I do the above implementation with the positions as I described

Comment: Yes, now I see you are using `memset` in your code. Perhaps you can use `memcpy`? I mean collect the four numbers in an array and latter copy them to array of zeroes starting from desired position using `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use calloc... have a look at this 
http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-calloc